# Vim Diffing a pair of Unicode little endian without BOM text files in a readable format?

Tags: vimdiff, encoding

I have a pair of ["Unicode little endian without BOM"](https://superuser.com/questions/902499/icacls-viewing-permissions-relative-to-the-root-of-a-folder?noredirect=1#comment1210536_902499) text files that I would like to diff each other via the command line.  Unfortunately when I open them using the command line in vim for Windows they come up as a bunch of unreadable binary symbols because the encoding WinMerge is expecting is wrong.

Is there any way to feed these into vim in a readable format?

Answer (score 6):

Vim's name for that encoding is `ucs-2le` (`ucs-2` for Unicode, 2 byte per character, `le` for little endian). You can open that via

```
:edit ++enc=ucs-2le filename
```

enforcing the encoding, or alternatively (if you open such files often), add that encoding to the list of detected ones:

```
:set fileencodings^=ucs-2le
```